# How to setup action access control?

Tags: smart-contract, permissions, authorization

Let's say `contract-A` has a couple of actions defined. If access to one of the `contract-A`'s action, say `action1()`, needs to be controlled on account basis, how to do it?

For example, only few accounts (or `account@custom` only) should be able to trigger `action1()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from the smart contract side, use [`require_auth2`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#require_auth2):

```
void contractA::action1() {
   require_auth2(N(account), N(custom));
   // rest of the action
}
```

If you want to do it from the user side, use [`$ cleos set action permission`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/v1.3.0/reference#cleos-set-action-permission):

```
$ cleos set action permission <account> <contractA> <action1> <name_of_permission> -p <account>@active
```

Comment: Well, from contracts perspective, require_auth2 ensures that the 'account' has 'custom' auth. But any account's owner can create the required custom auth and trigger the required action. So, contract owner couldn't restrict the access in this scenario.

Comment: And the command line command, authorises the <account>'s custom permission <name_of_permission>, to trigger the <action1>. This also being controlled by the caller's account and not the contract's account. I'm looking for access control by the contract itself in a flexible way.

Comment: `require_auth2` as exemplified above ensures that the caller is `account` so no other account can call it regardless of how they set up permissions. and yes, the second example is meant to be controlled by the user not the contract. it shows 2 different ways to do it depending on requirements

Comment: yes, thats right, require_auth2 ensures the caller is account. But what I'm looking for is, the access should be given to a selected set of accounts while rest of the accounts should be blocked to trigger the contract in a flexible way.

Comment: yes, the first parameter of `require_auth2()` is the specific account... `require_auth2(N(alice), N(custom)` followed by `require_auth2(N(bob), N(custom)` would only allow `alice@custom` and `bob@custom` assuming `{bob, alice}` is your set of selected of accounts

Comment: Thanks @confused00 for explaining. Above example apart from ensuring that alice and bob only accesses the account, but also requires both of them to be signed-on on each push of the contract's action. I'm looking for the support where bob and alice only allowed to access the account and they should be able to trigger the contract's action independently. It would be awesome, if there is a provision to add/remove accounts from the authorised list (which has alice and bob now) without redeploying the contract.

Comment: i see. for this case, i believe the second option is more appropriate then. you'd have a `require_auth(_self, N(custom))` in the action you want guarded, and `_self` (which is `contractA`) would need to use `cleos set permission` to give permission to `bob` and `alice` to `contractA@custom`. can't test it right now

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I couldn't make it work. It would be great if you could share the working instructions.